# Pivotear un DataFrame con MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un archivo .xlsx el cual tiene celdas combinadas y paso los datos del archivo a un DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("miArchivo.xlsx", sheet_name='KPIs', header=[0,1])
```

Output:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado pivotear el DataFrame mediante:

```
df2 = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Enero 2019', 'Febrero 2019', 'Marzo 2019', 'Abril 2019', 'Mayo 2019', 'Junio 2019'], columns=['Proyecto', 'TIPO KPI', 'General/Espec', 'Concept', 'Metric']).reset_index()
```

pero debido a que el DataFrame tiene MultiIndex presenta el error:

```
ValueError: Grouper for 'Enero 2019' not 1-dimensional
```

Quisiera poder obtener un DataFrame de la siguiente manera:

```
|              | Real          | Target       |    Proyecto   |    TIPO KPI   |      Metricas      |
| ------------ | ------------- | ------------ | ------------- | ------------- |  ----------------  |
| Enero 219    |      10       |      30      |   Proyecto 1  |    Numerico   |  Proyecto 1 Metric |
|              |      20       |      10      |   Proyecto 2  |    Numerico   |  Proyecto 2 Metric |
|              |      30       |      20      |   Proyecto 3  |    Numerico   |  Proyecto 3 Metric |
| Febrero 219  |      651      |      200     |   Proyecto 1  |    Numerico   |  Proyecto 1 Metric |
|              |      500      |      100     |   Proyecto 2  |    Numerico   |  Proyecto 2 Metric |
|              |      200      |      55      |   Proyecto 3  |    Numerico   |  Proyecto 3 Metric |
| .......      | .......       | .......      | .......       | .......       | .......            |
| .......      | .......       | .......      | .......       | .......       | .......            |
```

Comment: ¿Podrías proporcionar un enlace al xlsx, o a otro simplificado o con datos falsos si los tuyos no se pueden compartir, pero que tenga la misma estructura para hacer pruebas?

Comment: Lo puedes consultar acá: [enlace](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZlZBrJ2kXxKhIy8EJgE1ox8EayoYzN60/view?usp=sharing)